# DD4T APPLICATION Integration with DXA 2 MODEL SERVICE

Tags: dxa, topology-manager, dd4t-2, model-service

We are planning to integrate DD4T APPLICATION Integration with DXA 2 MODEL SERVICE using below Article

http://blog.trivident.com/switching-to-the-dxa-2-model-service-in-your-dd4t-application/

We are using Topology Manager to publish the Website.

As per The below stack exchange URL
[Web 8 Topology Mapping with DD4T applications](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17558/web-8-topology-mapping-with-dd4t-applications/17597#17597), we don't need to add BaseUrl.

Since DD4T will be using Publication Resolver is it required to configure my DD4T localhost URL as part of BaseUrl in Topology manager as I am consuming DXA 2 MODEL SERVICE?

Comment: Did you decide to use DD4T together with DXA 2 Model Service? I am curious because I have some issues related to the Model Service Converter and the DD4T provider for the Model Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Website Base URL confugured in Topology Manager is used in several places, including the “View On Site” Feature in the CME.

For that purpose, you want to set the Base URL to the actual (remotely accessible) URL of your Website, even if the web app doesn’t do Publication URL resolving.